# pandas read_sql_table never resolves

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am experimenting with SQL and Pandas.
Following the pandas guide for [sql queries](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries) and the associated `sqlalchemy` [engine specification guide](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html)

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
'''
example from sqlalchemy guide, engine_spec has the form of:

    dialect+driver://user:password@host:port/name

where leaving out "+driver" defaults to whatever the SQLAlchemy choose for dialect  
''' 

my_engine_spec = 'mysql://user:password@host:port/name'
engine = create_engine(my_engine_spec)

data = pd.read_sql_table(table_name, engine, chunksize=10)
```

Things to note:

- I limit `chunksize` to 10 and there are more than 10 records in the table. This is for testing to make sure the code works without waiting for the data dump... but nonetheless it does not resolve
- I am using `mysql` with default driver and I went through the pain of installing it on macOS with python3+
- I waited over 5 minutes before terminating the script.
- I can instantaneously see the data using an SQL DB visualizer app of choice (e.g. Sequel Pro) with the same specs, so assume the variable `my_engine_spec` is correct.

Why does this take so long or not even resolve? how can I speed it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I limit chunksize to 10 and there are more than 10 records in the table.

Pandas read whole table in chunk, and each chunk have 10 records or less. When you specified `chunksize` that `pandas.read_sql_table` will return a generator.

```
data = pd.read_sql_table(table_name, engine, chunksize=10)
[data.__next__() for _ in range(1)] # only read one chunk, 10 records or less
```

> I waited over 5 minutes before terminating the script.

`read_sql_table` will read a whole table, all records. That means if you want to use `read_sql_table` a very huge table then select the special column, you will spend much more time and memory, compare to finishing it inside mysql. ***Why you spend so long which is associated with what you did through your code***, if you only run that your example code shows, it should be fast(i have tried to read 0.5M records, but it only costs a few seconds)

> Why does this take so long or not even resolve?

If you don't need all records, so use `read_sql` or `read_sql_query` to run queries. Because MySQL does very well.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. I am also working with ~0.5M records, but it takes `317s` to run the code you provided in your answer.  I use `chunksize` as I hoped it would be faster than reading the whole table, and there are not that many columns. Regarding `read_sql`, "This function is a convenience wrapper around `read_sql_table` and `read_sql_query`" (according to pandas docs)...

Comment: If you insist loading whole table, you can transform file to other file type then read it. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#performance-considerations